# Select unique values(based on two columns) in group by mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL.
I have written following query in MySQL

```
select * from msgs where (msgs.toid = 1 or msgs.fid = 1) group by fid,toid;
```

this query returns values as shown below.

```
|message_id | toid | fid |
    68          4     1 
    70          1     9
    72          1     4
    78          5     1
    80          9     1
```

My expected result should be

```
|message_id | toid | fid |
    72          1     4
    78          5     1
    80          9     1
```

It mean I should not get repeated values(based on two columns values toid,fid) and it should be the highest id value.

*The combination of toid and fid should be unique.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `greatest(),least()` to check whether another row with the same combination of id's and a higher message id does not exist (which means the selected row has the highest message id for the given combination).

```
select * from msgs m where (toid = 1 or fid = 1)
and not exists (
    select 1 from msgs m2
    where greatest(m2.toid,m2.fid) = greatest(m.toid,m.fid)
    and least(m2.toid,m2.fid) = least(m.toid,m.fid)
    and m2.message_id > m.message_id
)
```

EDIT - another way using `row_number()`

```
select * from (
    select * , 
        row_number() over (partition by greatest(toid,fid),
          least(toid,fid) order by message_id desc) rn
    from msgs m where (toid = 1 or fid = 1)
) t1 where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this.

```
select * from msgs m 
        where (toid = 1 or fid = 1)
          and not exists ( select 1 from msgs m2
                                   where (m2.toid + m2.fid) = (m.toid + m.fid)
                                     and m2.message_id > m.message_id
                         )
```

Comment: Wouldn't eliminating group by result in an error because of the aggregate function (max)?

Comment: You could also replace the greatest and least functions in @Fuzzytree's answer by comparing just the sums of fid and tid.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM msgs m
WHERE NOT EXISTS (  SELECT 'a'
                    FROM msgs m2
                    WHERE m2.msg_id > m.msg_id
                    AND (
                          (  m.toid = m2.toid
                             AND m.fid = m2.fid
                          )
                        OR ( m.toid = m2.fid
                             AND m.fid = m2.toid
                          )
                        )
                   )
AND (m.toid = 1 OR m.fid = 1)
```

Return the last messages for conversation between two user

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT
  MAX(message_id) AS message_id,
  LEAST(toid, fid) AS toid,
  GREATEST(toid, fid) AS fid
FROM
  msgs
GROUP BY
  LEAST(toid, fid) AS toid,
  GREATEST(toid, fid) AS fid
```

yes it will return for example

```
80    1    9
```

instead of

```
80    9    1
```

but since `(1,9)` is equivalent to `(9, 1)` it should not be a problem. If it is, see FuzzyTree's answer.